# How to run program in nested project in IDEA IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, configuration, ide

I have a directory contains a lot of directories which are standalone project themselves.

I open this big directory in IDEA IntelliJ

```
    .   
    ├── 1.1
    │   ├── java-8.iml
    │   ├── out
    │   │   └── .......
    │   ├── src
    │       └── com
    │           └── Main.java
    │
    ├── 1.2
    │   ├── java-8.iml
    │   ├── out
    │   │   └── .......
    │   ├── src
    │       └── com
    │           └── Main.java
    ├── 1.3
    │   ├── java-8.iml
    │   ├── out
    │   │   └── .......
    │   ├── src
    │       └── com
    │           └── Main.java
    .......
```

**if I open "1.1" alone in IDEA IntelliJ, the button for running the script will appear.**

However, If I open this big directory.  **Only Edit Configurations... options are shown**.

Even if I want to try to add this Application after press the button,
the ide report that **Warning: Class 'Main' not found in module**

[image: only edit configurations option]

[image: Main class not found]

**So, my question is,**

**1. how to add this application in edit configuration?**

**2. Are there any more intelligent ways that I can run this script without edit any configuration?**

Comment: You need to select the Main class that you want to run. Start by clicking the button with "..." which is in the same row as "Main class:".

Comment: When I want to do something like that I usually see a green triangle on the left of every `public static void main(String[] args)` and their class header. I just click them to run what I want.

Comment: @Sterconium there are no such green triangle on the left of my main function of class Main

Comment: @KentShikama __Main class not found error__ in big directory   is reported

Comment: Try to mark your `src` folder as **sources root** (right click on it on your project explorer)